# Is there any way to get the photo of the books that a user likes on facebook after loging in on website?

Tags: javascript, php, facebook-graph-api, yii

So I managed to implement the user login facebook button on my website, and successfully get the books that the user likes on his personal facebook page, but this returns only the ID of the book and the name.

I was wondering if there is any way I could get more info about the object, like : what type of book is it ( SF, Action, For kids etc... ) or at least a photo for it, if there is any on facebook for it.

Any ideas on how I can manage to do this?

As a side note ( dunno if it will give any ideas for you guys ), I'm making an e-commerce website that after you login with your facebook account on the website I want to recommend those books that you liked/read on facebook, but I can only do that if I know them, and if the website doesn't have them I would like to make a new db entry with them, that's why I want to get more details about the item ( photo, gender etc.. )
The same I would like to apply even for movies and Songs.

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you make a query with `me/books`, or `v2.0/user_id/books`, here's a sample result:

```
       {
      "category": "Book", 
      "name": "Atharva Veda", 
      "created_time": "2012-01-22T16:27:00+0000", 
      "id": "111018182244878"
    }, 
    {
      "category": "Book", 
      "name": "Petronius' Satyricon", 
      "created_time": "2012-01-22T16:24:45+0000", 
      "id": "107943872570178"
    }, 
    {
      "category": "Book", 
      "name": "De Brevitate Vitae", 
      "created_time": "2012-01-22T16:24:44+0000", 
      "id": "108092199212156"
    }, 
{
      "category": "Book", 
      "name": "Myth of Faraway Winds, an Ebook by Sarah S. Vati", 
      "created_time": "2012-08-20T23:26:20+0000", 
      "id": "390942770973133"
    },
```

The category is, unfortunately, just "book" (I also see community pages or interests in the list of my books), but you have the book title. You can get a description with the book id, i.e., `v2.0/book_id`. If we want info about the book with id 390942770973133, we call the url `v2.0/390942770973133`, and here's the result:

```
   {
  "id": "390942770973133", 
  "about": "Myth of Faraway Winds is a special issue of Sarasvati Gallery's Art Catalogues, featuring the event \"Sarasvati Gallery in Atessa (Abruzzo, Italy)\".", 
  "can_post": true, 
  "category": "Book", 
  "checkins": 0, 
  "description": "Myth of Faraway Winds is a special issue of Sarasvati Gallery's Art Catalogues, featuring the event \"Sarasvati Gallery in Atessa (Abruzzo, Italy)\".", 
  "has_added_app": false, 
  "is_community_page": false, 
  "is_published": true, 
  "likes": 2, 
  "link": "http://www.smashwords.com/books/view/217352", 
  "name": "Myth of Faraway Winds, an Ebook by Sarah S. Vati", 
  "parking": {
    "lot": 0, 
    "street": 0, 
    "valet": 0
  }, 
  "talking_about_count": 0, 
  "were_here_count": 0
}e_count": 0
    }
```

You get the book cover at the following url: `https://graph.facebook.com/BOOK_ID/picture`, so, for the book above, it would be `https://graph.facebook.com/390942770973133/picture` (that's not a query, it's the url that redirects to the book picture. Put it in your browser to see it).

Comment: Thanks very much, marked your answer as correct :D this will help me very much, just a side question : the same applies for movies ?

Comment: yes, you do a query with `/v2.0/me/movies` and a sample result is as follows  `{
      "category": "Movie general", 
      "name": "Tríptico Elemental de España", 
      "created_time": "2013-01-01T01:59:59+0000", 
      "id": "126807864008570"
    }, ` then you can get more info about the movie with the movie's id